# C define 64bit on 32bit

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

If I do:

```
#define TIMEFIXCONST 11644473600
```

on a 32bit machine, will it overflow or will it be stored as a long long and still work properly? Should I just define a global unsigned long long and use that instead?

Comment: If you are afraid of overflow, may I suggest you use the suffix "L"?

Comment: If you need it to be a long long, the correct suffix is 'LL', of course; a single 'L' indicates long.  This assumes you have a compiler that supports C99.

Comment: `11644473600L` may still be of type `long long`. But no suffix is really needed; the constant is of whichever type (`int`, `long`, `long long`) that can hold its value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A macro is only a text substitution, you can't overflow a macro.
It depends on where do you assign later TIMEFIXCONST.

But as a rule of thumb, when using constants use `const int` or `const long long` if you require.

Answer (score 3):

The number is not "stored" anywhere. It will just be inserted in the program source code where you use the macro, just as if you had written it directly. But if you want the literal itself to be of type long long, write:

```
#define TIMEFIXCONST 11644473600LL
```

Answer (score 1):

A (non?)standard way to do that would be

`#define TIMEFIXCONST 11644473600LL`

Then it will be treated as "long long".  What happens after that depends on the statement you use it in (overflow, etc).  If you try to assign it to a 32-bit variable it will get truncated and the compiler should throw a warning.

Comment: That's standard - as long as the standard is C99.  It's non-standard if the standard is C89.

Answer (score 0):

If you store this in an `int`, it will overflow on both x64 and x86. If you store it in a `long`, you wont have the problem on either platform. The `#define` has no bearing on memory.

Comment: It's not guaranteed to fit into a `long` either - `int` is a minimum of 16 bits and `long` is a minimum of 32 bits (and different x86 and x86-64 ABIs define these differently).

Answer (score 0):

```
#define TIMEFIXCONST 11644473600
```

Any use of the macro `TIMEFIXCONST` expands at compile time to the constant `11644473600`. It's not stored anywhere unless you store it.

A decimal integer constant is of type `int`, `long int`, or `long long int`, depending on the value of the constant and the ranges of the types (it's the first of those types that's wide enough to hold the value). There's no need to add an `L` or `LL` suffix unless you want to be explicit about the type. Even then, `11644473600L` may be of type `long long` rather than `long`.

(In C89/C90, it's of type `int`, `long int`, or `unsigned long int`, but if `unsigned long int` is only 32 bits the constant itself is an error.)

Since `11644473600` requires at least 34 bits (plus the sign bit if any), it's probably of type `long` if `long` is 64 bits, or `long long` otherwise.

If you assign that value to an `int` variable:

```
int n = TIMEFIXCONST;
```

it will be converted to `int`, and the result is implementation-defined. You'll *probably* get a compile-time warning; if you don't, find out how to enable more warnings in your compiler.